# Running an app in iOS from the start button in Xcode (version 15)

Tags: ios, xcode

My iPad shows up in the list of connected devices:
[image: the run device list]

but I can't select it as a destination to run on:
[image: the device list]

This was not a problem on older version of Xcode, I run Xcode version 15 at the moment, the minimum deployment target is iOS 15.4 the device is sunning iOS 15.7.

Which button do I click?

I found the device listed as connected under "Manage Run Destinations".

I get this error when I try to install a Simulator:
[image]

Comment: When you install Xcode 15 you have to wait for the iOS 17 runtime to finish downloading (based on my experience).

Comment: @DonMag Thanks. I tried to install the simulator several times but it fails every time. Any idea what I can try?

Comment: Quick searching ... looks like common cause is not enough drive space. Have you checked that? Keep in mind installs often require at least double the free space than you expect...

Comment: @DonMag Thank you! That was the case. Apple should hire you to write error messages.